# Object refernce not set to an instance of an object error is coming while creating new VisualC++ project in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I tried after updating and repairing the visual studio, still not resolved. Even I uninstall the Visual Studio 2017 and reinstall the visual studio. It didn't work at all, I even went through some solution in which devenv / command was there, I executed that command also. After all my attempt I'm not able to create the Visual C++ project.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that you have installed all of the dependencies for a Visual C++ project?

Comment: yes, universal c++ and Desktop C++ for ARM etc I have installed, then after it is not creating project showing same mentioned error